# How do I properly create new directories if they don't exist, and then copy files into them on the target install device?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to accomplish the following steps with the below rpm code:

1. Copy files into an rpm package from **device A** (host server or development server) using `rpmbuild -ba foo.spec`
2. The rpm package is built and manually transferred/downloaded to the root folder of the target: **device B**
3. Install the rpm package on **device B** using: `rpm -i test.rpm`
4. A directory is created /usr/local/etc/NS/enrich/*...etc during the install by the rpm package on **device B**
5. The files (source1 through source 4) are then copied into the respective directory on **device B**.

My code currently does not do this, but I don't understand why.

```
Name:       test
Version:    0.1
Release:    0
Summary:    This RPM is for transfering foo lists to a Test device.
License:    TODO
Source0: foo_foov4.csv
Source1: foo_foov6.csv
Source2: foos_approved.csv
Source3: s_all_foos_enriched.csv
Source4: s_foo_foobar.csv

%description
Test Build 0.1

#copy the files
%prep
cp -p %{SOURCE0} .
cp -p %{SOURCE1} .
cp -p %{SOURCE2} .
cp -p %{SOURCE3} .
cp -p %{SOURCE4} .

%install
%{__mkdir} -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_datadir}/%{name}/usr/local/etc/NS/enrich/foo_Approve/csv/
%{__mkdir} -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_datadir}/%{name}/usr/local/etc/NS/enrich/foo_/csv/
%{__mkdir} -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_datadir}/%{name}/usr/local/etc/NS/enrich/foobar_WildApprove/csv/
%{__mkdir} -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_datadir}/%{name}/usr/local/etc/NS/enrich/foobar_Wild/csv/

%{__install} -m 644 -p foo_foov4.csv \
    $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_datadir}/%{name}/usr/local/etc/NS/enrich/foo_Approve/csv/
%{__install} -m 644 -p foo_foov6.csv \
    $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_datadir}/%{name}/usr/local/etc/NS/enrich/foo_Approve/csv/
%{__install} -m 644 -p foos_approved.csv \
    $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_datadir}/%{name}/usr/local/etc/NS/enrich/foobar_fooApprove/csv/
%{__install} -m 644 -p s_all_foos_enriched.csv \
    $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_datadir}/%{name}/usr/local/etc/NS/enrich/foo_/csv/
%{__install} -m 644 -p s_foo_foobar.csv \
    $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_datadir}/%{name}/usr/local/etc/NS/enrich/foobar_foo/csv/
%files
%{_datadir}/%{name}/usr/local/etc/NS/enrich/*
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not installing

```
/usr/local/etc/NS/enrich/*
```

but

```
%{_datadir}/%{name}/usr/local/etc/NS/enrich/*
```

So you should find your files there on your target machine.

Comment: `rpm -qlp filename.rpm` is your friend. (You can also use `less` in most RedHat-ish distros.)